# Calculating joint probability distribution of two random variables.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The joint probability distribution of two random variables $X$ and $Y$ is given by:

$p(x,y) = A(x+y)^2$ for $x$ and $y$ in $[0,1]$.

1) What is the value of $A$?

ans. $A$ = $\frac{6}{7}$

2) What is the conditional probability density of $y$ given $x$, $p(y|x)$?

ans. $\large \frac{(x+y)^2}{x^2+x+\frac{1}{3}}$

3) What is the probability density of $y$, $p(y)$?

ans. $A(y^2 + y + \frac{1}{3})$

4) What is the expected value of $y$?

ans. $\frac{9}{14}$

5) Are $X$ and $Y$ independent? What is the reason?

ans. No Since $p(y)\neq p(y|x)$

I graduated university some year ago so I forget probability theory. Very unfortunately, I really can not find relevant knowledge to solve the questions as I do not know suitable keywords.

Could you let me know how to solve those questions?

Comment: What is $(x,y)^2$?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I have no idea. I really would like to understand it, but the context is limited so I can not solve it. This questions are come from the book for Kalman filter exercise as pre-requisite knowledge, and I understand how the filter works but I just can not understand those questions :(

Comment: Oh.. is there anybody who knows the reason or at least relevant subject?

Comment: Can you give the title of the book? Certainly there's some information that's missing or presupposed from earlier in the book.

Comment: It appears the probability density function is $(x + y)^2$ on the unit square. Can you solve the problems if you know that?

Comment: Dear Tyler, you are totally right. It was x+y, not x,y.

Comment: No. Very unfortunately. I understand how to solve bayes rule, and even linear regression concepts, but I realized that I forget very basic concepts in probability.

Comment: I can solve and understand 4) 5) based on the answers from 1)2)3) but I can not solve 1) 2) 3) because I forget how to derive it from the equation. I guess it may be a very easy question for whom already knows it, but for me, it is even hard to search to find relevant document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p(x, y) = A(x + y)^2$.

1. We know that since $p(x, y)$ is a probability density function, we must have $\int_0^1\int_0^1p(x, y) \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y = 1$. You need to solve this integral for $A$.
2. $p(y | x) := \frac{p(x, y)}{p(x)}$. To calculate this, you need to find the marginal distribution of $x$, which you get by integrating $y$ out of the probability density function, or $p(x) = \int_0^1 A(x + y)^2 \mathrm{d}y$.
3. $p(y)$ is calculated in a similar way to $p(x)$ was in the previous problem.
4. $E(Y) = \int_0^1 yp(y) \mathrm{d}y$.
5. If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $p(y|x) = \frac{p(x, y)}{p(x)}=\frac{p(x)p(y)}{p(x)}=p(y)$.

All of this should be covered in a standard undergraduate probability book (the ones targeted at math/statistics students). The book my university used was [this one.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321500466) I'm sure if you look online you can find an open source book that covers everything you'd need to know.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much.